# Units of length in Poincare half plane model

Tags: differential-geometry

The hyperbolic geodetic distance in the half plane model is a pure number since it is given by formulae which are ratios of lengths (using either the cross ratio or the arsinh formula). So what is the unit of length?  Deriving the length in the arsinnh formula requires specifying x and y cartesian coordinates, so could their graduations be used as the standard.
Also in deriving the half plane metric uing the hypershere with base radius R, we assume that R is equal to 1, so have we implicitly defined a unit of length?

Comment: Thank you but I am still a little confused. Using ruler and compass, I mark two points on the half plane model. I can then construct the semi circle joining the two points and, using the ruler, measure four lines and calculate the geodesic between the original two points using the cross ratio. Can't I then choose the point (0,i) anywhere I like and thus construct a random unit of measurement for the geodesic? Or is the point (0,i) specified as soon as I mark the two original points?

Comment: On further thought, I agree with you. For now, I'm hoping someone else will answer this.

Comment: I was wrong about this and have deleted my original comment. No units are needed, because the hyperbolic distance depends only on ratios, as the cross-ratio formula demonstrates. If you have two different pairs of points, but you can map one pair to the other using horizontal translation and dilation (both are isometries), then the distance between the points in one pair is equal to the distance between the points in the other pair. As a consequence, it does not matter what units you choose.

Comment: Yes, I can see that but how does this relate to the Boylyai-Lobachevsky formula connecting a distance to an angle. So I could select a point p and a line l and then construct another line m bisecting the asymptotics to l meeting it at a second point q.  The BL formula gives the length of the new line in terms of the angle of parallelism. If I calculate the segement pq using cross ratios will i get the same length.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Boylyai-Lobachevsky formula. Perhaps you could add an explanation of it?

Comment: In half plane, from a point p construct asymptotes to a hyperbolic line L. Bolyai Lobachevsky formula is   tan(theta/2) = e^-D where theta is angle of parallelism and D is the hyperbolic distance from point p to line L.

Comment: Could you give a reference? Or a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Here's my guess of what the BL formula is: it is based on a right triangle where one leg is the geodesic segment connecting the two points and the opposite vertex is at infinity. The angle of parallelism appears to be the angle between the geodesic segment and the (infinite) hypotenuse. The statement is that the length of the segment is uniquely determined by the angle. The formula can be found using standard hyperbolic geometric formulas. My guess is that this is the BL formula.

Comment: So in the half-space model, you would first draw the semicircle connecting the two points. Then find the unique semicircle passing through one of the points and perpendicular to the first semicircle. Finally, you find the semicircle that passes through the other point and is asymptotic to the second semicircle on the real axis. The angle of parallelism is the angle between the first and third semicircles. You probably can derive geometrically how this is related to the cross-ratio.